# How to WaitAll on AutoResetEvent and Monitor

Tags: c#

I have to sync on two "event sources" at once (WaitAll) the problem is one of this "event sources" is Monitor. My "fast and dirty" solution is :

```
AutoResetEvent OuterSyncAutoResetEvent...
const string GetSyncContextLockString...

while(true)
{
    lock (GetSyncContextLockString)
    {
        if (OuterSyncAutoResetEvent.WaitOne(0) == false)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

is there more "modern" way?

Comment: Because `Monitor` uses a different wait mechanism to `AutoResetEvent` there is no API available to wait for both. You'll have to do it like you already are.

Comment: If you have the possibility of changing the program to change the Monitor to an AutoResetEvent then you can use WaitHandle.WaitAll() on the two AutoResetEvents. That would be much less kludgy.

Comment: 99.9% odds that this code is hiding a threading race bug.  It works when the lock is contested, it will *not* work when it is not.